# Keycloak how to change Forgot Password redirect url

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, saml

I am using Keycloak for authentication, and I want to configure the `Forgot Password` feature to redirect users to my password reset website `https://mypassport.xxx.com`. Could you please guide me on how to set this up? Thank you!

[image]